# Why did Dumbledore swim instead of fly?

Tags: harry-potter

In *The Half-Blood Prince*, Harry and Dumbledore go on a Horcux hunt. They have to cross the sea to reach the island. Dumbledore and Harry swim. Why do so?

The water was as cold as ice (this might not be a problem to Dumbledore) and they swam with robes on, I believe. Swimming with robes in freezing water doesn't sound like such a good idea.

Dumbledore could have flown (Wingardium Leviosa) or summoned a broomstick etc.

Dumbledore cared about Harry - yet he made him swim in bone chilling water. Why?

Comment: He didn't want to disturb the magical 'vibrations' in there by doing any magical stunts // the cave entrance was so small above water, they wouldn't have been able to fly in or turn around if it was a dead end

Comment: Dumbledore made Harry do a *lot* of dangerous things.

Comment: Wingardium Leviosa is for levitating objects, presumably not people. Unaided flight is only ever shown to be a Dark Art in the Harry Potter books (it's only ever done by Voldemort and Snape).

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is: We don't know.  But:

We do know that getting through the wall inside the entrance requires that the wizard attempting entrance 'weaken themselves', as Dumbledore puts it - in this case, payment in blood.  It is not entirely unreasonable to speculate that Voldemort placed a similar enchantment around the entrance - in that case, 'weakening themselves' by forcing exposure to biting cold.  Dumbledore wouldn't necessarily have explained that then because (a) Swimming isn't magical and so requires no special explanation, hence it might not have occurred to Dumbledore to explain himself right then; (b) The noise of the pounding surf outside the entrance made speech impractical.

Comment: Not unreasonable but there isn't anything to indicate this was the case is there? If there is please [edit] it into your answer.

Comment: Not convinced - the warming charm is a very simple counter to this.

Answer (score 1):

**There wasn't room to fly**

The opening in the rock face was described as a "fissure" which would be very narrow.  It is also described as being so low that high tide would cover it.

> The fissure soon opened into a dark tunnel that Harry could tell would be filled with water at high tide.  The slimy walls were barely three feet apart... The Cave p.557 HBP

Later it is said that the seawater "filled" the crevice.

> ...Harry helped Dumbledore back into the icy seawater that filled the crevice in the cliff. The Cave p.578 HBP

Tides, of course, can vary widely and we are not given any specific details but the impression given is that they would not have fit through any higher up.